# Trouble with Readline and regex matching

Tags: java, regex, readline, bufferedreader

I have a (ANSI) text file (filters.txt) on my computer, on each line is a regex.

In my main, I loop through an RSS feed; each item is passed to another method to check for matches in filters.txt.

The problem is nothing seems to be matching.

- The string I'm passing to the method is correct (tested)
- My regexps are correct (tested)
- Input from filters.txt "seems" to be the same as in the text file
- Perhaps a line break or something else is screwing up the pattern matches? Do i need to use some other tool to read the text files to get this done?

Here's the code of my method:

```
public static boolean filtermatch(String rsstitle) {
    boolean result = false;

      try {
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filters.txt"));
          String strLine;

          while ((strLine = br.readLine())!= null && result == false) {
              if(Pattern.matches("(?i)" + strLine, rsstitle)) {
                  result = true;
              }
          }   
          br.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
      }

    return result;
}
```

EDIT:
Only filter i have on right now:

```
\\[HorribleSubs\\].*Chihayafuru.*
```

Should be matching "[HorribleSubs] Chihayafuru - 12 [720p].mkv" yet it's not. It matches it if I define the regex in the program though.

Comment: Added, check the end >.<

Comment: `new FileReader("filters.txt", "Cp1252")` explicitly states that the file is in Windows code page 1252, Windows variant of Latin1. Now it uses the operating system default.

Comment: @JoopEggen: I agree that you should specify the encoding, but FileReader doesn't let you do that.  You have to use an InputStreamReader wrapped around a FileInputStream instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put double backslashes in the file: Java will transform them in "\\\\". It reads a single backslash like "\\".

Comment: Aaaaaaaaannnnnnnnnndddddddd it's working!
Thanks a dozen, would never have figured that out myself :)

Comment: @lelouch Yep, reading in strings is not the same as constructing them--escaping is only relevant in the source itself.